# Kendo Grid :TypeError: $(...).saveAsExcel is not a function

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

`saveAsExcel` is not working and is throwing error.

> Kendo Grid :TypeError: $(...).saveAsExcel is not a function

Below is my code:

**jquery files included:**

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

**Kendo Grid:**

```
<button class="k-button" id="button">Export Excel</button>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WealthWizard.Common.Entities.UserLoginEntity>()
            .Name("grid").NoRecords("No Records Found(s)").Excel(o => o.AllPages(true).FileName("xyz.xls"))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {                columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).
                ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("WWView", "Dashboard", new { Area = "Admin", AffID = "#= ID #' " }) + "#= FirstName #' " + ">#= FirstName #</a>")
                .Width(150).Title("First Name");
                columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("Email"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.Phone).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("Phone"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.StateName).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("State"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.Stars).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("Stars"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.ContactsProfiled).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("Contacts Profiled"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.Leadsregistered).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("Leads Registered"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.ContestWon).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("ContestWon"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.UserLastActivity).Width(150).Filterable(false).Title("Last Activity"); ;
                columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedOn).Width(150).Title("Created On").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            })
            .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.
            Template(@<text><input class='k-textbox' value="Search..."
                                   onfocus="if (this.value=='Search...') this.value='';"
                                   onkeyup="fFilterChanged()"
                                   onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Search...':this.value;"
                                   id='searchbox' /></text>))
            .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 650px;" })
            .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .PreviousNext(true)
            .ButtonCount(5)
            )
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("WealthWizard_Read", "Dashboard").Data("GetFilter"))
            .PageSize(50)
   ))
```

**Function:**

```
$('#button').click(function () {
     var gridview = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
     gridview.saveAsExcel();
});
```

Comment: is the grid populating any data? Also, that could be because there isn't a kendo.min.js file as that is what calls that function

Comment: yes , the grid populates data from server side ... Also i have added the following files :

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

I think i have included all scripts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right version of javascriot files for kendo excel export. As of the Kendo UI Q3 2014 (2014.3.1119) release, the Grid widget provides a built-in Excel export functionality.

Answer (score -1):

In Kendo View Page :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GroupContact1>()
.Name("gridKendoSearchBycategory")
**.Events(s=>s.ExcelExport("Excelexportname"))**

<script>
function Excelexportname(e) {
e.sender.saveAsExcel();
}
// In Events if not seen ExcelExport please update kendo Js version 2018.
</script>
```

U can Also Use In Kendo Grid Mvc For Download Excel :

```
.Excel(excel => excel.FileName("ContactByCategoryExcel.xlsx")
.Filterable(true)
.AllPages(true))
```

**Before All That Please check your kendo version because some feature not working properly in older version, you can use version 2018.3.1017.545**